# Bootstrap slider - prevent flipping the two cursors and stop slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use Bootstrap slider to represent 3 lengths of axes whose sum doesn't change (the max value of the slider corresponds to this sum).

So I have 2 cursors on bootstrap slider and the 3 intervals represent these lengths.

Here's an example: [bootstrap with two cursors](http://jsbin.com/detapa/2/edit?html,js,output)

My issue is that I would like to stop dragging the second cursor (on the right) when it is equal (or nearly with a fixed step) to the first one (on the left) and inversely for the first cursor.

I saw there's an slide stop event but this doesn't seem to be the same thing.

I have surely to modify the bootstrap-slider.js source but I don't know how to do for implementing this specific functionality.

It would be like:

```
slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
if ((cursor2.value - cursor1.value) < step)
  { this.stopSlide();}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using slides events it's possible. The idea is to see which cursor is fixed, and when its value change, block the slide movement, by setting value.
Didn't find a cleaner way to block slide event...

Working code :

```
var slider = new Slider("#slider1");

var initPos,
    fixedCursor,
    fixedCursorPos;

slider.on("slideStart", function(slideEvt) {
  initPos = slideEvt;
  fixedCursor = null;
  fixedCursorPos = null;
});

slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
  if (initPos[0] !== initPos[1] && (slideEvt[0] !== initPos[0] || slideEvt[1] !== initPos[1])) {
      if (fixedCursor == null) {
        fixedCursor = (slideEvt[0] === initPos[0] ? 0 : 1);
        fixedCursorPos = slideEvt[fixedCursor];
      }
      if (fixedCursorPos !== slideEvt[fixedCursor]) {
        slider.setValue([fixedCursorPos, fixedCursorPos], false, false);
      }
  }
});
```

Working JS Bin : http://jsbin.com/kopakiciti/1/edit?html,js,output